# Is there a hardware-constrained method for removing content from the internet?

Tags: hardware, scam

I recently came across this viral post on Facebook:

[image]

---

As of the time of this question, the post has more than 37,000 likes, 33,000 shares and 1.5k comments. Most of the comments are positive, interspersed by the occasional techie questioning why someone would need such a powerful PC to request nudes to be taken down from the internet, and speculating that it may be a scam.

Like those techies, to my knowledge the only way to remove someone's content on the internet is to request the host to take them down, but is this true?

Is there any conceivable computationally-intensive method in which nudes could be taken down from the internet, or is this likely to be a scam?

Comment: No there is not, unless you count DoS (which will be constrained by your Internet connection), or using that nice GPU to crack server passwords or something ridiculous.

Comment: He might be running multiple scrapers and image recognition software to automate search for copyright contents. Most of the leaked contents are uploaded with different titles at various location so he needs to recognise if all of them are same.

Comment: Easy way to find out. Put some pictures up on the internet, and DM that person for help taking it down. Then see what they do.

Comment: Yeah, it's easy, I can remove images from the internet too: just open "dev tools" in your browser, find the image tag, and then add the CSS line "display:none". Done! I'm kidding. But what I want to say is that unless we define what "remove from the internet" means, we have no way to guess what he could be doing. It could be anything from a simple takedown request to search engines, to a scam where he gets to know your FB name and associate it with your nude pic (then proceeds to blackmail you).

Comment: Maybe he launches denial of service attacks from his box and then gets _himself_ banned from the sites and assumes they're offline for _everybody_? I can't see any way this would work, though I _can_ see that this might help him get donations to buy more hw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is brute-forcing password hashes, which doesn't seem very likely.

1. This person would need the password hashes to attack offline.
2. He would have to not be able to alter the hashes (otherwise he could reset the password)
3. He would have to be external: An internal person could directly remove the pictures.